# SelectedItem from CollectionView doesn't refresh automatically when Selection is changed

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I can't find out why my ToolbarItem Text isn't refreshing automatically when I change the SelectedItem on my CollectionView. I don't have much experience with xamarin, c# or coding in general but I can't imagine thats a big thing to implement.

I tried to debug the problem with some stops at the "AktuellesProjekt" Property but it didn't help that much. I just don't know what to do to fix this.

`<ToolbarItem Text="{Binding AktuellesProjekt.Name}" Order="Primary"/>`

[image: Example]

ViewModel:

```cs
public class DashViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //Name
    public const string ViewName = "DashPage";
    
    //Konstruktur
    public DashViewModel()
    {
        //Titel
        Title = "Dash";

        //Commands intialisieren
        LadeProjekte();
    }

    //Commands


    //Fields
    private ObservableCollection<ProjektModel> _projekte = new ObservableCollection<ProjektModel>();
    private ProjektModel _aktuellesProjekt = new ProjektModel();

    //Properties
    public ObservableCollection<ProjektModel> Projekte
    {
        get { return _projekte; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _projekte)
                return;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Projekte));
        }
    }

    public ProjektModel AktuellesProjekt
    {
        get { return _aktuellesProjekt; }
        set
        {
            {
                if (value == _aktuellesProjekt)
                    return;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AktuellesProjekt));
            }
        }
    }

    //Methoden
    public void LadeProjekte()
    {
        for (int i = 2020; i <= 2040; i++)
        {
            var projekt = new ProjektModel
            {
                Name = i,
                BestandGesamt = 12000.00 + (i - 2020) * 1000,
                LetzteAktualisierung = "31.12." + i.ToString(),
                AnzahlEintraege = 76 - (i - 2020) * 10
            };

            Projekte.Add(projekt);
            AktuellesProjekt = Projekte[0];
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource NormalBackgroundColor}"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
             
             xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:DXApp3.Resources"
             xmlns:dxcv="http://schemas.devexpress.com/xamarin/2014/forms/collectionview"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:DXApp3.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:DXApp3.Models"
             
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             x:Class="DXApp3.Views.DashPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding AktuellesProjekt.Name}" Order="Primary"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:DashViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
                <dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Projekte}"
                                       SelectedItem="{Binding AktuellesProjekt}"
                                       SelectionMode="Single">
                    
                    <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="10,10,10,10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                                       Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Finanzen {0}'}"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="18"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>                        
                    </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    
                </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
            </ScrollView>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="1" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#1968B3" CornerRadius="25" TextColor="White" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Margin="0,0,20,22">
                <Button.ImageSource>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="fa-solid" Size="Medium" Glyph="{x:Static fa:FaSolid.Plus}" />
                </Button.ImageSource>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue #1: Missing update of backing field

First of all, you're not actually updating the backing fields here:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ProjektModel> Projekte
{
    get { return _projekte; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _projekte)
            return;

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Projekte));
    }
}

public ProjektModel AktuellesProjekt
{
    get { return _aktuellesProjekt; }
    set
    {
        {
            if (value == _aktuellesProjekt)
                return;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AktuellesProjekt));
        }
    }
}
```

You need to set the backing fields to `value`:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ProjektModel> Projekte
{
    get { return _projekte; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _projekte)
            return;

        _projekte = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Projekte));
    }
}

public ProjektModel AktuellesProjekt
{
    get { return _aktuellesProjekt; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _aktuellesProjekt)
            return;

        _aktuellesProjekt = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AktuellesProjekt));
    }
}
```

## Issue #2: ToolbarItem not updating

Now that the `AktuellesProjekt` gets updated properly (or at least it should), based on your comment, I've done a quick search and came across [issue #14886](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14886). It seems that bindings on `ToolbarItem`s don't work properly.

### Workaround

A workaround would be to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the ViewModel in the code behind and then manually update the `Text` property of the `ToolbarItem`:

```cs
public class DashPage : ContentPage
{
    private DashViewModel _viewModel;

    public DashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        if(BindingContext is DashViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if(_viewModel != null)
            {
                _viewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }

            _viewModel = viewModel;

            _viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(_viewModel.AktuellesProjekt))
        {
            TitleItem.Text = _viewModel.AktuellesProjekt.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, you'll also need to provide the `x:Name` attribute to the toolbar item:

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="TitleItem" Text="{Binding AktuellesProjekt.Name}" Order="Primary"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

### Simplification

This can be simplified a little, if you don't set the `BindingContext` in the XAML, but rather in the code-behind.

Remove this from your XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:DashViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And then your code-behind could look as follows:

```cs
public class DashPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly DashViewModel _viewModel;

    public DashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new DashViewModel();
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(_viewModel.AktuellesProjekt))
        {
            TitleItem.Text = _viewModel.AktuellesProjekt.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was obviously missing in my code. But it didn't fix the Problem unfortunalety. The Toolbar text still isn't updating when i change the selection in the collectionview.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check if this solves your problem now.

Comment: Hey Julian, thanks for the update. I tried both of your Workarounds, but neither worked. When I use the simplification nothing changes compared to before. When I use the not simplified workaround the ToolbarItem is disappearing completely.

Comment: @Felix Sorry, I was out for a while. That's strange. Have you found a solution in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to achieve this.

First, you need to create the CollectionView with the method `SelectionChanged`.

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="Toolbaritem"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
        ...
    </CollectionView>
```

Second, you can realize the method `SelectionChanged` by using the following code. Then, You need to get the data from the `CollectionView` and pass the data to the `ToolbarItem`.

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       var entity = (Entity)e.Item;
       Toolbaritem.Text = entity.Name;
    }
```

This method will pass the data to the ToolbarItem everytime after you press the CollectionviewItem.